# NetSuite: How to source {orderdoc} and {orderid} in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches, purchase-order

I'm trying to create a transaction saved search for actuals in NetSuite in order to integrate the results to some third-party platflorm for reconciliation.

However, I can't seem so get the {orderdoc} (Purchase Order the current transaction is tied to) and the {orderline} (Line number on the purchase order the current transaction is tied to) to show in the results.

I can substitute the {orderdoc} to the createdfrom field, but I can't seem to et the orderline to work.

I tried the following:

- Formula (Text) on the Results tab with value of {orderline}
- Created From : Line Sequence Number
- Purchase Order : Line Sequence Number

All of them did not work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What Transaction Type is the "current transaction"?  What Criteria and Results are you using currently?  What results are you getting, and what do you expect/desire?